# Finding a k element subset in a set of real numbers (Programming Pearls book)

Tags: algorithm

I am solving problems from Column2 of Programming Pearls. I came across this problem:

"Given a set of n real numbers, a real number t, and an integer k, how quickly can you determine whether there exists a k-element subset of the set that sums to at most t?"

My solution is to sort the set of real numbers and then look at the sum for the first k elements. If this sum is less than or equal to t, then we know there exists at least one
set that satisfies the condition.

Is the solution correct?

Is there a better or different solution?

Note: Just to make it clear, do not assume the input to be already sorted.

Comment: Could we see your code? It doesn't really answer how quickly you determine the subset of the set exists. What is the time complexity does it take to sort and compare the sums in your implementation?

Comment: If you are allowed to use a lot of space you can use the relatively common trick of building a heap. Building a min heap is linear `O(n)`. Extracting the first `k` elements is `k * log(n)` so the total algorithm is `O(n + k*log(n))`. I'm pretty sure there's a linear solution though.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch IMHO, code is not required to understand this problem and I don't have it yet. But assume I am using the best sorting available, O(nlogn) would be the sorting / preprocessing time. Now, sum of k numbers can be O(n) in worst case. But overall this gives an idea. I will post the code too once I have it ready.

Comment: Ah I think I have a solution. Use quick select to find the `k`th largest element. Then iterate through the list to find the `k-1` elements less than or equal to it. Sum them. That's `O(n + k + k)` which is linear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you need only first k elements sorted as per your problem , I suggest following:-

1. Select the kth element in array using randomised select O(N)
2. Take sum of first k elements in array and check if its less than t

Time complexity `O(N + k) = O(N) as k is O(N)`

[Randomized Selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect)

**Note**:- when k is very  small as compared to N then max heap can be very efficient as the storage does not cost that much and it can solve problem in worst case O(Nlogk).

Comment: Yep, I just got the solution too. Cool

Comment: Quick select as they call it is an amazing algorithm to study . Just like the analysis of it.

Comment: I think you guys went about this wrong, unless I am miss interpreting the question.... forget what you know about quickselect for a sec. Basically, you need to find a possible combination of k elements to make it add up to the totalSum (t). `Set (n)={1,1,2,3,4,5}` `total sum (t) = 7` `subset size (k) = 2`. Quickselect will say false, as it will select 1,1. If you take 3,4 you get totalSum.

Comment: @jonovate No i think you misunderstood the problem , it says the sum of k element subset must be atmost t not equal to t so the smallest k elements will always have smaller sum then any other combination so if first k elements have higher sum than t then all other combinations will have higher sum.